# Code inside activate function of VS Code Extension is not run

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, activation

I am trying to have the `activate` function of my VS code Extension to install another extension and set some settings.

The function `set_private_repo` runs well when triggered manually by a registered command, but is not run automatically by the `activate` function.

Any idea why?

```js
import * as vscode from "vscode";

const default_registry = {
    name: "Registry for Private Exensions",
    registry:
        "http://myrepo:8082/artifactory/api/npm/vs-code-extensions/",
    enablePagination: false
};

export function deactivate() {}

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    install_private_extensions();

    await set_private_repo();

    // We will add a command to remove filter on the registry
    // And a command to set the Theme
    // ... and to set private repository, in case "set_private_repo" has not been called
    let cmd_set = vscode.commands.registerCommand(
        "myextension.setPrivateRepository",
        set_private_repo
    );
    context.subscriptions.push(cmd_set);

    let cmd_set_theme = vscode.commands.registerCommand(
        "myextension.setTheme",
        () => {
            let config = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration();
            config.update(
                "workbench.colorTheme",
                "My Theme",
                vscode.ConfigurationTarget.Global
            );
        }
    );
    context.subscriptions.push(cmd_set_theme);
}

function check_registry_found(registries: Array<Object>): boolean {
    let found_registry = false;
    registries.forEach((reg: object) => {
        // @ts-ignore: Does not know what is "reg"
        if (reg["registry"].includes("myrepo")) {
            found_registry = true;
        }
    });
    return found_registry;
}

// Update registry of Private Extensions in user settings
async function update_registry(registries: Array<object>) {
    await vscode.workspace
        .getConfiguration()
        .update(
            "privateExtensions.registries",
            registries,
            vscode.ConfigurationTarget.Global
        );
}



// install extension and set registry
async function install_private_extensions() {
    const private_ext_manager = "garmin.private-extension-manager";
    // We will install Private Extension Manager automatically to be able to update the theme more easily
    if (vscode.extensions.getExtension(private_ext_manager) === undefined) {
        await vscode.commands.executeCommand(
            "workbench.extensions.installExtension",
            private_ext_manager
        );
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage(
            "Installed Extension for Private Extension Manager"
        );
    }
}

async function set_private_repo() {
    await install_private_extensions();

    let registries: Array<object> = vscode.workspace
        .getConfiguration()
        .get("privateExtensions.registries", []);

    // If registry not found, we will add one
    if (!check_registry_found(registries)) {
        registries.push(default_registry);
        await update_registry(registries);
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage(
            "Private Repo for Extensions added"
        );
    }
}
```

The activation trigger in **package.json** is the following:

```
    "activationEvents": [
        "onCommand:myextension.setPrivateRepository",
        "onCommand:myextension.removeRegistryFilter"
    ],
```

Thanks

Comment: I assume the missing `async` is just a typo in the question

Comment: Anyway, include the activation section of your package.json https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/activation-events

Comment: @AluanHaddad Indeed, I have moved back & forth between `async` and sync and ended up with something in between :) And you might point out something indeed: shall I have a `*` in my activation? :)

Comment: `activate` function runs when the extension has been activated which runs when you defined in `activationEvents`. If you want the extension to be active when vscode is opened, you should add (or leave only) `*`. https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/activation-events#Start-up

Comment: @MoshFeu I actually got that after the comment from Aluan ;)

Comment: So, I'm an unnecessary person, got it ;)

Comment: No, you confirmed what I thought :)

Comment: And you linked the documentation. That's very helpful